# Feedback panel transparent issue

Tags: html, css

Hi guys I have a feedback form which works using jquery... You you click on "feedback" which as a fixed position. The form slides.

**Issue**

when the form slide open the contents on the page can't be clicked because the contents on the main page overlays it.

**I have try**

I have try using

```
z-index:-1px;
```

but the issue with this is that I cannot click on the textbox or submit button on the feedback panel.

**Question**

what is the best way to solve this problem please?

Comment: A jsFiddle link or live link will help us to know your issue better.

Comment: You can try to put the forn in sepreat div (not inside any div) or maybe you are using the "z-index" property wrong. jsFiddle  or your art of the CSS code will be great

Comment: @NaveTseva I have added the code here instead

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` should be an integer value not defined in pixels so simply use `-1`. Although I would elevate the form with a high z-index rather than lowering others which could break the page.

Comment: if i use `z-index:1` thats works because the button to close the feedback panel is behind it which means u cant close it u will need to refresh the page to close it